# Expression Engine - PHP error, endif

Tags: php-errors, super-admin

I have a site using EE 2.5.2.  When logged in as a super admin, on some accounts we get the following error when clicking on a link in one section of the site:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDIF in /var/www/html/system_giy/expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(680) : eval()'d code on line 692

This only happens on some Super Admin accounts. Other super admin accounts work fine.

Update with code block from template. `<div class="grid_12">
  <section class="light_brown_flat">
    <div class="{if '{exp:stash:get name='is_editor'}' == 1}grid_8 omega{if:else}grid_11{/if}">
      <h3>{title}</h3> {exp:switchee variable="{group_status}" parse="inward"} {case value="Public"} {exp:stash:get name='meetings'}
      <p class="summary">{imported_description}</p> {if group_champion}
      <h3>Group Contact(s)</h3>
      <p>{group_champion}</p>
      <p>{group_champion_phone}</p>
      <p>{group_champion_email}</p> {/if} {group_documents} {if row_count == '1'}
      <div id="documents">
        <h3>Public Documents</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><i class="foundicon-inbox"></i><a href="{doc_file}">{doc_title}</a></li> {if:else}
          <li><i class="foundicon-inbox"></i><a href="{doc_file}">{doc_title}</a></li> {/if} {if row_count == total_rows} </ul>
      </div> {/if} {/group_documents} {/case} {case value="Private"} {if "{exp:stash:get name='is_member'}" == 1} {exp:stash:get name='meetings'}
      <p class="summary">{imported_description}</p> {group_documents} {if row_count == '1'}
      <div id="documents">
        <h3>Public Documents</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><i class="foundicon-inbox"></i><a href="{doc_file}">{doc_title}</a></li> {if:else}
          <li><i class="foundicon-inbox"></i><a href="{doc_file}">{doc_title}</a></li> {/if} {if row_count == total_rows} </ul>
      </div> {/if} {/group_documents} {if:else}
      <p>This group is private. You must be a member of the group to see information on it.</p> {/if} {/case} {/exp:switchee} {if "{exp:stash:get name='is_editor'}" == 1} {exp:channel:entries channel="giy_documents" entry_id='9385' dynamic='no' disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"}
      {if count =='1'}
      <div id="admin_documents">
        <h3>Featured Admin Documents</h3>
        <ul> {/if} {documents_files}
          <li><i class="foundicon-inbox"></i><a href="{document_file}">{document_caption}</a></li> {/documents_files} {if count == total_results} </ul>
        <p><a href="/{segment_1}/admin_documents/{segment_3}">All Documents</a></p>
      </div> {/if} {/exp:channel:entries} {/if} </div> {if "{exp:stash:get name='is_editor'}" == 1}
    <div class="grid_4 omega"> {exp:channel:entries channel="announcements" sort='desc'dynamic='no' disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"} {if count =='1'}
      <div id="announcements">
        <h3>Announcements</h3> {/if}
        <article>
          <h4>{title}</h4> {exp:trunchtml chars="120" inline="..." }
          <span>{exp:strip_html}{announcement_text}{/exp:strip_html}</span> {/exp:trunchtml} <a class="read_more" href="#" data-reveal-id="announcement{count}">Read More</a> </article> {if count == total_results} <a class="archive" href="#">Announcement Archive</a>        </div>
      <div id="announcement{count}" class="reveal-modal announcement">
        <h5>{title}</h5>
        <p class="lead">{announcement_text}</p> <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a> </div> {/if} {/exp:channel:entries} </div> {/if}
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </section>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div> {/exp:channel:entries} {/if}`

Comment: Could you post the relevant code block from that template? Start at least a few lines after 692, and go back 20 lines or so.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I've updated the question above with the block of code.

Comment: nn... No, I don't need to see lines of code from a core library, I need to see the template code for the page that is causing the issue :p

Comment: Hi again, the template doesn't have 692 lines in it, just 113, but I've pasted in the relevant section from the template.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by commenting out sections of the code to isolate which field(s) are throwing the errors - once you do that, you should be able to track down what the issue is; I think I've seen bugs like this when there are poorly handled single/double/curly quotes in fields.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your help.  I think it was an issue with Stash in the end, fingers crossed.